# Rails replay to a message to moderator or admin - depends on created_at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app currently just displays a message which a client received after applying for a product. I want to give to the client the ability to reply to the original message from the moderator and saved it in his inbox (moderator inbox). However if the original message from moderator is older than 3 days, message should be routed to an admin and saved it in his inbox (admin inbox).

The app has 4 models:

`user.rb`

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :inbox
  has_one :outbox
  has_many :messages

  scope :client, -> { where(is_client: true) }
  scope :admin, -> { where(is_admin: true) }
  scope :moderator, -> { where(is_moderator: true) }
end
```

`message.rb`

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :inbox
  belongs_to :outbox
end
```

When a user sends a message, it goes into their outbox and into the inbox of the recipient:

`inbox.rb`

```
class Inbox < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages
end
```

`outbox.rb`

```
class Outbox < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages
end
```

I'm trying to something like this:

`MessagesController.rb`

```
def show
  @message = Message.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @message = Message.new
end

def create

  @message = Message.create(
  if current_user.message.created_at > 3.days.ago
    outbox: moderator.outbox
  else
    outbox: admin.outbox
  end
)
end
```

If I assume that I've only one moderator and one client should I have to create another controller to catch this message which I want to reply?

Comment: send the `id` of the original message in params, in the `create` action find the message with that `id`, check the `created_at` and assign inbox

Comment: Ok but if the original message is: `Message.create(body: 'Thanks for your order! ...', outbox: moderator.outbox, inbox: client.inbox)` and user wants to reply to this message, how to implement your solution?

Comment: in the link that you are using to open this page, pass the `original message id` as a query string for `new`. then store that id in a hidden field in the form as `= hidden_field_tag :original_message_id, params[:message_id]`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming in user inbox theres a link to reply to original message

```
= link_to 'Reply', new_message_path(message_id: orignal_message_id_goes_here)
```

`message_id` will be passed as a query string

```
= form_for @message do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :original_message_id, params[:message_id]
  ...
```

this will submit `original_message_id` with form data

```
def create
  orignal_message = current_user.inbox.messages.find_by(id: params[:original_message_id])

  inbox = if orignal_message.created_at > 3.days.ago 
             orignal_message.moderator.inbox
          else
             # find admin and get inbox
          end

  @message = Message.create(
    inbox: inbox
    body: params[:message][:body]
  )
end
```

Comment: I have in my show.html.erb `<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path, class: "btn-primary" %>` how should I update this? In this it takes me to the `new.html.erb` where after click on submit button I'm getting `undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: you are getting `undefined method ` because `orignal_message ` is `nil`. You have to pass the `id` of the message that user received after placing the order to the reply link `new_message_path(message_id: message_received_after_placing_order.id)`

Comment: where this `message_id` come from? and the big question is how to get this `message_received_after_placing_order.id` to not get undefined method? I'm totally stuck here